# Google Maps buttons not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with google maps. When i firstly embeeded iframe to my page on ipad i saw buttons like streetview under the map. When i switched maps to be generated from system data, and rendering using javascript api buttons are gone?

Is there a way to show them again, is it just an options that needs to be added to map or buttons only work when using iframe?

```
  var map;
               var service;
               var infowindow;

               function initializeMap() {
                   var slocation = new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);

                   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                       center: slocation,
                       zoom: 15

                   });


                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: 'example content'
                });

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: slocation, 
                    map: map,
                    title: ' example title'
                });


                infowindow.open(map, marker);
               }
```

the buttons that i want to achive are http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/43/buttonsuv.png/

Comment: ...and please post the javascript which generates your map.

Comment: Perhaps : map.setOptions({
    streetViewControl: true
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, add this option `streetViewControl: true`

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       center: slocation,
       zoom: 15,
       streetViewControl: true
});
```

Have a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview), it summarises all of the street view options.

**UPDATE**

After the question update, I realise you want your custom image on the street view icon.
That's not possible.

One workaround is to define a custom control on the map, and link events to it with the streetview events.
I've never done it, however you might want to have a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls)

Comment: those buttons are on site when i embeed iframe into it and using ipad, not when using js, so i think those buttons comes from google, you are sure this is not possible from API?